# How to centre a position:fixed element - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have searched far and wide, but cant seem to find an answer for my particular question: I have a div which is 980px wide, and position:fixed to remain at the top of the page as you scroll down. My problem is that i cant work out how to centre align the div, and keep it centred whilst also being position:fixed rather than position:relative

any siggestions, or am i missing something obvious??

Comment: Code? Code! code please?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply this CSS style:

```
div#id {
    position:fixed;
    top:0; /* or whatever you need */
    left:50%;
    width:980px;
    margin-left:-490px; /* half the lenght of the element */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the right answer of GionaF, here's a live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ubp49/